# Laravel Homestead nginx issue

Tags: laravel, nginx, homestead

So, I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway when I try and load my sites in my Homestead environment.

Whenever I load my vagrant box I get the following error:

```
nginx stop/waiting
==> default: nginx start/running, process 1858
==> default: php5-fpm: unrecognized service
```

I've found I need to edit my `etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file.  But I don't see an nginix folder in my `/etc` directory.

Note:  I installed this environment by pulling `git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead`.  It seems I don't have nginx installed but it should have with the package of Homestead I grabbed.

http://screencast.com/t/Wmuydv2zw6

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete al boxes from this folder .vagrant.d\boxes wich is located in your home directory. Then download the box and clone the homestead directory again.